# rails: collection_select for current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Box which has many Items which belongs to a Category.
When the Box is created it has the user_id.
Items has a category_id.

I've seen that if you have a user_id in the table concerned it works okay:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.where(:user_id => current_user.id), :id , :name %>
```

But how can I get a Category collection_select from what the current_user has entered - do I have to add a user_id to Categories or can I join my tables somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this way is easier:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, current_user.categories, :id, :name %>
```

PS: Even better if you put this in your controller, so, in case you have to change the select and add some clauses, you will not need to change almost all your views, just the controller (MVC).

Comment: I did try that and I get undefined method `categories' for #<User.       Categories only has two fields, its ID and NAME

Comment: so, in your user model put `has_many :categories`, and I will assume that you have in you category model a `belongs_to :user`.

Comment: with that I get the error: column categories.user_id does not exist

Comment: so I strongly believe that your model is wrong. Create a migration that adds the column user_id to the categories model.

Comment: thanks. you set me on the right track - I added the user to Items, and set the User to have many Categories through Items.